# Идеи по дизайну фотогалереи

Tags: дизайн, иконки

Сейчас размышляю на тему создания thumbnail для альбомов с фотографиями:

http://twimp.ru/?act=test

Дашел пока до этого. Фотографии динамически подставляются (по ссылке это всегда одни и теже, но генерируются автоматически) в иконку.

Мои знакомые отвечают на такое довольно не однозначно, одни говорят, что им лучше thumbnail'ы обычные, т.е. просто ресайз, другие говорят, что так очень круто.

Вот и задаю вопрос - кто какие где видел, может кому что понравилось, может есть какие-нибудь идеи. Спасибо :)

Comment: Ого. Думаете, найдутся дураки такие идеи бесплатно раздавать?) Я бы не стал))

Comment: Хм... Ну я думаю, что кто-нибудь где-нибудь просто видел интересные вещи.

Comment: А, в этом смысле… Тогда я точно пас: я видел либо когда просто одна из фотографий, либо как по ссылке (ну или как в Windows7).

Comment: То что сейчас, не разглядеть совсем фотографию, можно только догадаться если раньше видел их.

Comment: Поэтому я и задал вопрос, потому что сейчас не видно фотографий, просто есть какие-то и все. Самый простой вариант - это тумбы, но это и самый обычный, а хочется сделать что-то необычное.

Comment: Я оставляю этот вопрос открытым, поскольку он имеет интересный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил как в Win7 там кстати 2 фотографии используются и папки я бы желтые сделал, не отвлекают от фотографий и более прозрачными чтобы акцентировать внимание на фото, да и тень уберите она тоже отвлекает.
Более оригинальным было бы изображение не папки а допустим альбома, возможно уголки для крепления фото или странички на пружине.

Comment: Вариант был сделать как палароидные фотки, т.е. с рамкой по краям, с рандомным углом поворота на плоскости.

Comment: Как вариант широкий альбом с загибающимся титульным листом и фотографией на первой странице и все это под углом.